# What does ひと足ふた足抜け mean here?

Tags: meaning, sentence, idioms

> ありがとうございます。多様性の時代をチャンスとして捉えるという意味ですよね。私も話していてすごく体感するのが、ひと足ふた足抜けてD&Iに取り組んでいらっしゃるので、本当にグローバルなイノベーションにつながると思います。真に多様性の尊重されるような組織をつくれたら、という思いに共感していますし、応援しています。

This is the conclusion of a talk about equity in the workplace where they brought a guest who works for supposedly leading company in that area (双日株式会社｜Sojitz Corporation)
Where the host says the phrase :ひと足ふた足抜け" which i coud not exactly find after searching, the closest thing i found is
足抜けて which is defined as つらい状況・境遇などから抜け出すこと。But I do not think this is how it is used here ! Am I correct in my understanding that it means somthing along the lines of "leading by a step or two" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think your understanding is correct. While ひと足先に and 一歩抜け出す are common expressions, ひと足抜ける is not. Still, it's reasonable to guess it's supposed to mean "他の人より1、2歩先に" or "他の人に先駆けて".